# How can a potentiometer boost a voltage signal?

Tags: potentiometer

I was looking at this project a person did to make their Prius regenerate more power instead of letting it go to waste on brakes:

[image]

This probably sounds dumb to you, but it boggles my mind.  How can a potentiometer boost a voltage signal?

Let's say we tweak the pot to only let 0.1 volts through from the 5V supply to the ECUU. If there is 2 volts coming from the pressure signal, and it combines with the .1 volts, the voltage won't change. It will just stay 2 volts.

I have no idea how a potentiometer would multiplY two voltage sources.

I just want to try this because the guy scrapped the idea because he said while the fuel economy increased a ton, he didn't think many people would like it because it would brake not smoothly because it was a static increase in braking. I think that's pretty dumb and if you just put a big enough capacitor on the signal wire it would smooth it out.

Comment: A potentiometer can’t boost a voltage signal, although it could be part of a circuit that does.  In the circuit, however, it attenuates the signal from the pressure sensor and so a higher pressure is required to achieve the same signal to the ‘ABS ECU’, although exactly what effect that would have is unclear .  I was under the impression that Prius’ do regenerate already, certainly it’s entirely normal for electric and hybrid vehicles.

Comment: hey frog, the priuses do regenerate, however the way it works is that, it will create equal braking divided between the regeneration and the brake master cylinder. So priuses only regenerate HALF of the power when stopping, which is what i'm trying to tackle here.

The signal is 0.15 volt to 4 volt, and so I'm trying to have an increased signal to the ecu

Comment: Hopefully nobody tries to drive with home-modified brakes. Mods void the type certification because the system is no more the same as the accepted reference system. Driving with one's own system is allowed only in driver's own private area and the insurances very likely are void if they do not explicitly allow experimenting. BTW. The usual hobbyist grade electronic parts and construction methods do not stand the violent environment that vehicles offer.

Comment: Don't see what this has anything to do with electronics. However I've witnessed many accidents, and participated in them, and filed claims, the latest one, I had someone steal a catalytic converter. Anyway if you were an insurance agent, you'd probably know that no car ever gets investigated like that. Insurance agents just blame the accident on an individual, and hold that person accountable. They will instantly blame it on driver error and no one is gonna be looking at your brakes.

Comment: but seriously I asked for a physics type of explanation how a pot can be used to manipulate a signal. I'm not here for unsolicited advice and flame wars with people who think it's best to conform with everything, never use your brain, and never change anything in life. I can write a book on all the messed up stuff car manufacturers do to screw the consumer and the planet, and you're just endorsing them, including this Prius brake scandal where the regeneration system only works half power PERMENANTLY.

Comment: That depends on where one lives. It's the property of the local culture. Somewehere you surely can drive legally with what you want as long as the right persons get the right payment (and you succeed to stay alive) or you belong to the elite who do not make payments, but collect them.

Comment: If a person dies a detailed analysis may be made of whole situation. This will depend on administration concerned and 'other factors'. If a vehicle has less braking power than it ought it can make a life and death difference.  The difference may only be 10-15% if regenerative braking fails. It MAY be that a skilled driver may have been able to stop and it MAY be that the driver was skilled and that the added regen braking would not have saved a life. Either way, if an investigation find the brakes were 'illegally' modified the consequences are potentially the same regardless.

Comment: It just adds in a bit of positive DC offset from the 5V supply. Not boosting anything. And it adds several potential failure modes you probably don't want to think about. But I'll leave you with this : what happens when the pot's wiper goes open circuit?

Comment: A possible issue is the maximum regeneration rate that the battery can support and remain within charging specs. I do not know if this is an issue in practice but it may be. Some manufacturers use an LTO battery as a front end to the main battery (NiMH or LiIon) in order to utilise LTO's very high charge rate tolerance.

Answer (score 1):

A potentiometer doesn't pass a specific voltage.  It is a variable resistor. A potentiometer **can not** increase a voltage.

As shown, the potentiometer is **reducing** the signal from the pressure sensor, but also **adding** an offset from the 5V source.

The net effect is to give the ECU a (mostly) constant signal that is influenced (somewhat) by the pressure sensor.

The "smooth braking" problem can't be fixed with a capacitor because it isn't caused by variations in the signal to the ECU.  It is caused by reducing the operating range of the brake.  In a regular car, it would be like having a brake pedal with a very short range - say, 1/4 inch over which you have to try to dose your braking effort.

---

From the comments, it seems that you would like to know how it works as well as what it does.

The potentiometer and the two voltage sources (+5V and the sensor) form a [voltage divider.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voltage_divider)

A voltage divider provides an output voltage that is a fixed proportion of the voltages at its ends.

This is a voltage divider:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fycJve.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

---

That is a fixed divider.  Vout will be 2.5 volts.  That's half way between the top voltage (5V) and the bottom (ground, at zero volts.)

A voltage divider doesn't have to work between ground and a fixed voltage, though.

It can work between two fixed voltages:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fA8icS.png)</sup>

The output voltage there is half way between 5V and 1V - that's 3V.

A voltage divider doesn't have to be symmetrical.  I could make the two resistors very different, and get a different output voltage depending on the ratio of the two resistors.

Like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fPturV.png)</sup>

The output for this asymmetric divider is 4.545 volts.

Now, you can do the same thing with a divider between two different voltages:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fFDBET.png)</sup>

---

The output there is 4.727 volts.

This begins to get into the area where your proposed brake modification works.

When the two resistors are greatly different and you have a varying voltage on one end, the output will always stay close to the end of the voltage range with the smaller valued resistor.

The potentiometer makes a voltage divider between the 5V line and the sensor voltage.

If we take R1=R2 = 50000 ohms, then we get a voltage to the ECU that looks like this:

| Sensor voltage | ECU voltage |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | 2.5 |
| 1 | 3 |
| 2 | 3.5 |
| 3 | 4 |
| 4 | 4.5 |
| 5 | 5 |

That's added 2.5V, and "squished" the pressure sensor range to half of what it normally is.

Lets get even more extreme and set R1 to 1000 ohms and R2 to 99000 ohms:

| Sensor voltage | ECU voltage |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | 4.95 |
| 1 | 4.96 |
| 2 | 4.97 |
| 3 | 4.98 |
| 4 | 4.99 |
| 5 | 5 |

That's added 4.95 volts, and squished the pressure sensor range from its normal nearly 5V range into just 50 millivolts.

If you go the other way, and make R1 99000 and R2 1000 ohms, then you get an almost normal range on the pressure sensor:

| Sensor voltage | ECU voltage |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | 0.05 |
| 1 | 1.04 |
| 2 | 2.03 |
| 3 | 3.02 |
| 4 | 4.01 |
| 5 | 5 |

Your potentiometer is just an easy way to vary the two resistors of a voltage divider.  The sum of the two halves will always be 100000 ohms because that's the total value of the potentiometer.  The ratio can be varied to give any proportion you like.

Sort of like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fRhxKv.png)</sup>

That's a voltage divider made of just a potentiometer.  The two halves (split by the wiper) act as R1 and R2 in a fixed voltage divider.

That's all that's going on in your proposed brake modification.  The potentiometer is a variable voltage divider that adds an offset to your sensor voltage while scaling the sensor voltage to fit between the offset and the maximum (5V.)

---

Regardless of how this modification works (or doesn't work,) you shouldn't do it.

It will make your brakes unreliable.  The brakes won't be as effective as they should be, and your modifications may come unstuck in traffic - no matter how good you think you are with a soldering iron.

Do you really want to wind up in court and have to explain to the judge that you ran over that little kid because you modified your brakes to try to get better mileage from your batteries?  That comes across as "cheapskate kills kid to save dime."

Answer (score 0):

> *how can a pot boost voltage signal?*

It can't. A pot consumes power and is purely resistive; it cannot make a voltage bigger; only smaller.

> *I have no idea how a potentiometer would multiple two voltage sources*

Don't worry about it because it doesn't.

The guy who said he tried it is either a scammer or you have the wrong circuit.

Comment: uhh, this is the post if maybe i missed something idk https://priuschat.com/threads/how-to-increase-the-amount-of-regeneration-out-of-a-prius.135919/

Comment: That circuit does not regenerate anything on its own. The idea of the article is that the circuit you show "cons" the ECU into using a higher degree of regenerative breaking when slowing down.

Comment: yeah, the ecu is sensing 0.15 to 4 volts on that pressure signal sensor wire. So to con the ecu to giving more regeneration, we need a higher voltage on that 0.15 to 4 volt pressure signal wire. So we would have to boost it's voltage. And the article guy is doing that using the 5v supply and a pot, and my question is how does that work?

Comment: It isn't boosting the voltage (boost is a term we reserve for voltage converters); it's adding the voltage with 5 volts to make it overall a little higher.

Comment: so this works? I'm having a hard time visualizing the principles behind how this works, your explanation almost sounds like the pressure signal and the supply voltage are in series. But they are in parallel, and i thought adding voltages doesn't work, only the highest voltage stays and the lower voltage doesn't do anything

Comment: If you are familiar with op-amp audio mixer circuits you'd see resistors being used like this to mix (add signals); it's not exactly the same but close enough.